# using NLog for the first time

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I am using NLog for the first time in a winForm app which will be running for years may be. This app is also logging data in a text file. As the the app will be running for years so the text file will grow and grow. That’s why I want to limit the size of text file. Lets say when 10MB limit is reached the text file starts deleting the last entries to accommodate for the new data. How can I do it with NLog.

Some where in my c# project I have

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

logger.Trace("Error:.........."); // and similar msgs
```

My NLog.config is (it just logs data to a text file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/file.txt" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Can you please explain better what you mean (and what has NLog to do in all this)? Also show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @varocarbas NLog is used for logging

Comment: I want to take advantage from this incident to highlight how important is writing a proper description: from the current version of your question, it is clear what you mean exactly. Your original version was somehow misleading for anyone knowing about this tool and completely misleading for someone not having used this tool ever (like myself). As far as Nlog can be understood as N times logarithm (what I understood). The reason why I am explaining this is that I am lately finding quite a few "people", more interested in being misunderstood than in helping/being helped...

Comment: ... I do think that this is a minority but precisely to let them being a minority forever, better "fighting them" and avoiding this kind of behaviours to be present in a place like SO, meant for help, for proper knowledge and for quality information; not for allowing insecure, fanatical misunderstanders to grow.

Comment: TO THE OP: sorry for having written all this here; but I think that some awareness contributes towards improving SO and is beneficial to everyone: the clearer are the askers, the easier will be for the answerers to deliver an accurate solution and the happier will be everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit file size to 10MB and set max arhive files count to 1:

```
<target xsi:type="File"
      name="file"
      layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"        
      archiveAboveSize="10000000"
      maxArchiveFiles="1"
      archiveFileName="${basedir}/log_archived.txt"
      fileName="log.txt" />
```

When file will extend 10MB, it will be archived, and logging will continue to new file. When new file will extend 10MB, it will replace archived file. So, you will have two files - current and archived.

Comment: @varocarbas looks like he wants to use single file, which will keep size less than 10MB, and oldest entries should be deleted when new entries are added. But that is not possible with NLog, so I gave him alternative solution with two files - current one and archived one

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I deleted my comment when the OP updated his question with code. I misunderstood NLog completely.

Comment: thanks for the response. So you mean at all the time i will have two files one where i am writing and one archive file

Comment: @user2968369 exactly, maximum number of files will be 2. And at the beginning you will have single file (until it will be archived).

Comment: aha great. thanks. But the code you posted is giving me 'TypeInitializationException'

Typinitieraren for ConsoleApplication1.Program triggered an exception.

Comment: @user2968369 sorry, layout was incorrect, now updated. Also thus you have single archive file, you can use static file name, I'll also update

Comment: @user2968369 please, debug your application line by line and find source of error. It should be elsewhere - current configuration is correct

Comment: If it's a `TypeInitializationException` for `Program`, then it happens while initializing `static` members (like `logger`). So it is most likely related to the `GetCurrentClassLogger` method. Can you get the inner exception?

Comment: hmm, if i replace the code you posted with this there is no exception :( `<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/file.txt" />`

Comment: Note that your `writeTo="logfile"` attribute for the root logger must match the name of the target. @lazy used `"file"`, while you are using `"logFile"`.

Comment: @Groo yes you are right this exception is triggered by the `private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();`

Comment: sorry one more thing. No archive file is created. Do i need to make some changes here as well

`<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>`

I mean add a target here for archive file aswell

Comment: @user2968369 you need your `log.txt` file to exceed 10MB size for archive file to be created

Comment: i lowered the 10MB limit to 1KB to see the log creation. The log.txt remains lower than 1KB. New entries are not added to this file and no archieved text file is created

Comment: @user2968369 if you have configured all correctly, then after exceeding 1KB size, all log data should be copied to archive file and new empty log file should be created. If you don't see how new empty log is created, then it's size has not exceeded 1KB

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File"
      name="file"
      layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"
      archiveAboveSize="1000"
      maxArchiveFiles="1"
      archiveFileName="${basedir}/log_archived.txt"
      fileName="log.txt" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
`
I know you r right. I am not sure why i am not getting expected result

Comment: @user2968369 configuration is valid. Make sure you have logged enough entries of type INFO to exceed 1KB size